# g.DrawImage throws out of memory exception

Tags: c#, image, graphics, out-of-memory, drawimage

In my aplication I am working with about 30 - 70 large images. By working I mean loading, cropping, resizing and adding to aviStream. Each image can have up to 4500p and 10MB (working with such large images gives me most of the out of memory exceptions). While testing I sometimes use smaller ones (2500p ~ 500kB each) and the memory situation is much better.

I have changed the architecture of my program to: load one image, process the needed operations, add it to the stream, close it. And doing the same with next image. But due to the complexity and size of the code, I am not 100% sure that I dispose and close every bitmap and image created for temporary purposes during this proces.

I have the following error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll
```

Usually when cropping image:

```
public static Image Crop(Image imgPhoto, Point xy, int width, int height) {
        Rectangle cropRect = new Rectangle(xy, new Size(width, height));
        Bitmap target = new Bitmap(cropRect.Width, cropRect.Height);

        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(target)) {
            g.DrawImage(imgPhoto, new Rectangle(0, 0, target.Width, target.Height), cropRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        }

        return target;
    }
```

The exception is thrown based on the cropping level, if I crop small part of an large image, lets say 800x600 pixels in the middle, it is better. If a crop in the oposite way, lets say create an 3500x2500 image where the original image is smaller (blank space will be automaticaly filled with selected color), I have the exception most of the time.

One interesting thing is also that the exception is thrown around 23rd image, so previous images are procesed fine.

Can you guys give me an advice how to debug this? I have tried to scan the code for undisposed images and bitmaps, but it seems that I haven't found all of them.

The big question therefore is: How to proces all images one by one without having an exception?

Comment: I would say it's a Dispose problem, but how to find them easily... That's another thing.

Comment: Well, the `Bitmap` is not being disposed, and it is returned from the function. I assume the calling code doesn't dispose of it either. Also, perhaps try reusing the buffer if you are working with many large images, instead of reallocating it.

Comment: I am partially reusing them, but I have also a lot of these method where I return the original input image after some changes. If I am correct, there are only one image in this kind of situations and only a reference is being sent. So I can't dispose it, otherwise I will lose my original data, right?

Comment: In this function you are not returning the original image, you are returning a new one (`new Bitmap(cropRect.Width, cropRect.Height)`), where some data is copied from the original image. It is not possible for me to tell you how to do it efficiently with this little information. A way to "return" an image but avoid allocating it is allocating the "target" in the calling code, then sending it as a parameter to all the editing functions.

Comment: So should I dispose something here? using statement delete all block after finishing it, correct?

Comment: Here is the piece of code which call these method, I am using the original image for result: `image = ImageOperations.Crop(image, xyToCrop, xSize, ySize);`

Comment: _only a reference is being sent._ In the code you posted you __create a new__ Bitmap on each call. You create it, you dispose of it when done with it.  Did you try disposing imgPhoto before returning the target?

Comment: Thank you very much TaW. Haven't tried that because I thought it would delete "placeholder" for target, which is going to be returned into it. I have to say after couple of tests it works fine now. No exceptions, and RAM is not increasing during the operation. That seems to solve my problem, so once again, Thanks TaW.

Comment: it's been four months, do you have a solution or still the out of memory exceptions occur ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a bitmap inside the method you have to use the using block outside of the method, I mean where you call the method something like this:

```
using (var myNewBitmap = Crop(imgPhoto, xy, width, height) ) 
{

// do whatever you want with the bitmap 

}
```

after the using it will dispose and you will not get the exception. with the current code you can get the out of memory in the future.

Comment: Good - this is a cleaner solution than what OP says they did in a comment on their question. (comment says added a Dispose on the ORIGINAL bitmap rather than on the returned bitmap; without seeing their calling code, is impossible to know why that was successful...)